# GSON: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to My Generic Class

Tags: java, json, generics, casting, gson

Made one example that show my problem.
May be somebody have any idea ?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
>   JSONClassResponse     at Main.main(Main.java:8)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GetJSON<JSONClassResponse<JSONClass>> getJSON = new GetJSON<>();
        JSONClassResponse<JSONClass> jsonResult = getJSON.get();
        System.out.println(jsonResult);

    }
}

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class GetJSON<T> {
    public T get() {
        String buf = "{errcode:1,data:{value:[v1,v2,v3]}}"; // instant http request

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        Type tType = new TypeToken<T>() {
        }.getType();
        T t = gson.fromJson(buf, tType);
        return t;
    }
}

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class JSONClassResponse<T> {

    @SerializedName("errcode")
    private String errcode;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;
}

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONClass {

    @SerializedName("value")
    private List<String> value = null;

}
```